# MySQL - Pivoting rows into a dynamic number of columns

Tags: mysql

Good day! I am working with a timekeeping database which stores all of the states (working, break, coaching, etc.) an employee moves through as individual records, like so:

```
USERID | GROUPID  | STARTTIME           | ENDTIME
123    | 4557     | 2017-11-09 09:30:00 | 2017-11-09 11:48:43
123    | 8907     | 2017-11-09 11:48:44 | 2017-11-09 12:04:30
123    | 4557     | 2017-11-09 12:04:31 | 2017-11-09 15:04:22
```

and so on.

What I'd like to do is pivot this data, in MySQL, so that these individual records are all one line, like so:

```
USERID | PunchIn  | PunchOut | Break1_Start | Break1_End | Break2_Start ...
123    | 09:30:00 | 18:02:53 | 11:48:44     | 12:04:30   | 15:04:22
```

Is there a way to do this in MySQL that will dynamically staple on enough columns to totally encapsulate an employee's schedule (i.e., if they enter the Break Group ten times, it will add twenty columns to track the Beginning and End of each of those Breaks?)

Comment: How do those new columns relate to the original data? Where does the `PunchOut` value come from?

Comment: what does GROUPID mean in the context of the data?

Comment: GROUPID means which work-state a given Employee is in: 4557 is for Breaks/Lunches, 8907 is one of the Production groups for tracking productive time. Additionally, the column headers in the example pivot are simply things I've assigned myself. PunchOut, for instance would be the max(ENDTIME) grouped by the day.